# The frame color for MDRectangleFlatButton is not the same as the text

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

On the [KivyMD documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/index.html#mdrectangleflatbutton) it says:

> [image]
>
> Button parameters `MDRectangleFlatButton` are the same as button `MDRaisedButton`:
>
> ```py
> MDRectangleFlatButton:
>    text: "MDRECTANGLEFLATBUTTON"
>    text_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
>    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 0, 1
> ```
>
> Note that the frame color will be the same as the text color.

And [later](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/index.html#mdroundflatbutton) it says:

> Button parameters `MDRoundFlatButton` are the same as button `MDRectangleFlatButton`:
>
> ```py
> MDRoundFlatButton:
>    text: "MDROUNDFLATBUTTON"
> ```
>
> Warning:
> The border color does change when using `text_color` parameter.
>
> [image]

But when I run this code, it doesn't change the border color, only the text color itself.

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

kv_string = (
"""
ScreenManager:

    ScreenOne:
        name: "screen_one"
        id: screen_one

<ScreenOne>:
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Green"
        text_color: 0, 1, 0, 1

        pos_hint: {"center_y":0.5, "center_x":0.5}

"""
)


class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        kv_file = Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        self.root = kv_file


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

This is how it comes out:
[image]

---

Is there maybe a different way to change the button border for an `MDRoundFlatButton`? Am I doing something wrong in the code?

I'm using Kivy version v1.11.1 and KivyMD v0.104.1.

Comment: Your code runs fine. Which version are you using?

Comment: @ikolim I added a picture of the output. I'm running python 3.7 but I don't know what version of kivymd, I just did `pip install kivymd`.

Comment: @ikolim, Ok, kivy version v1.11.1, and kivymd v0.104.1.

Comment: There is a problem in KivyMD v0.104.1 but the problem is resolved in v0.104.2.dev0. If you want to use the development version, install it into your virtual environment using `pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip`.

Comment: @ikolim so there is nothing I'm doing wrong? I think I just won't use that feature. I don't really want to use a development version, but it will probably be updated in the future anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Same as [ikolim commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853816/the-frame-color-for-mdrectangleflatbutton-is-not-the-same-as-the-text/68912111#comment112954976_63853816):

In latest version `0.104.2` the [MDRoundFlatButton](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/?highlight=MDRoundFlatButton#kivymd.uix.button.button.MDRoundFlatButton.line_color) has a property `line_color`:

> Line color for button border.
>
> `line_color` is an `ColorProperty` and defaults to `None`.

Same as `MDRectangleFlatButton`.

Furthermore this property `line_color` is explained in [`kivymd.uix.behaviors.backgroundcolor_behavior.BackgroundColorBehavior`](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.2/behaviors/background-color/?highlight=line_color#kivymd.uix.behaviors.backgroundcolor_behavior.BackgroundColorBehavior.line_color):

> If a custom value is specified for the `line_color` parameter, the border of the specified color will be used to border the widget:

> New in version 0.104.2.
>
> `line_color` is an `ColorProperty` and defaults to [0, 0, 0, 0].